# JQuery Listener on Canvas Child doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

i have a problem i'm implementing a crop custom rectangle on a canvas i made a function in Javascript that when the crop function is called the create on existing canvas a child and then with the JQuery listener i draw the rectangle.The childNode is create correctly while the listener don't work they don't get the events. This is my code:

```
var dragging = false;
var xstart = 0;
var ystart = 0;
var width = 0;
var height = 0;
var ctxotmp = null;
var ctxtmp = null; 
var canvastmp = null;
var mycanvas = null;
function draw() {
 ctxtmp.fillRect(xstart, ystart, width, height);
}

function init() {
    mycanvas = $('#mycanvas')[0];
   // create temp canvas
    canvastmp = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvastmp.id = "mycanvastmp";
    canvastmp.width = mycanvas.width;
    canvastmp.height = mycanvas.height;
    mycanvas.parentNode.appendChild(canvastmp);
    $("#mycanvastmp").css({position:"absolute",top:$("#mycanvas").css("top"),left:$("#mycanvas").css("left")});
    canvastmp = $('#mycanvastmp')[0];
   ctxtmp = canvastmp.getContext('2d');
   ctxtmp.lineWidth = 1;
   ctxtmp.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
}
//listener
$('#mycanvastmp').mousedown(function(e) {
    var xoffs = $(this).offset().left;
    var yoffs = $(this).offset().top;
    xstart = e.pageX - xoffs;
    ystart = e.pageY - yoffs;
    dragging = true;
  });

  $('#mycanvastmp').mousemove(function(e) {
    if(dragging) {
      var xoffs = $(this).offset().left;
      var yoffs = $(this).offset().top;
      width = e.pageX - xoffs - xstart;
      height = e.pageY - yoffs - ystart;
      ctxtmp.clearRect(0, 0, $(this).width(), $(this).height());
      draw();
    }
  });

  $('#mycanvastmp').mouseup(function() {
    dragging=false;
    alert('The rectangle for crop (x, y, width, height): ' + xstart + ', ' + ystart + ', ' + width + ', ' + height);
  });
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: You should call init before setting listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.on` **[on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** in order to bind events to dynamically created objects. When your page initially loads and the dom fires, it doesn't see `tempCanvas` so it doesn't attach them initially.

```
//listener
$('body').on('mousedown' ,'#mycanvastmp', function(e) {

    var xoffs = $(this).offset().left;
    var yoffs = $(this).offset().top;
    xstart = e.pageX - xoffs;
    ystart = e.pageY - yoffs;
    dragging = true;
  });

  $('body').on('mousemove' ,'#mycanvastmp', function(e) {
    if(dragging) {
      var xoffs = $(this).offset().left;
      var yoffs = $(this).offset().top;
      width = e.pageX - xoffs - xstart;
      height = e.pageY - yoffs - ystart;
      ctxtmp.clearRect(0, 0, $(this).width(), $(this).height());
      draw();
    }
  });

 $('body').on('mouseup' ,'#mycanvastmp', function(e) {
    dragging=false;
    alert('The rectangle for crop (x, y, width, height): ' + xstart + ', ' + ystart + ', ' + width + ', ' + height);
  });

init();
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/GbM25/)**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're attaching the events before the temp canvas is created.
Either attach the events in the `init()` function after adding the temp canvas to the DOM or use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$("#mycanvas").on("mouseup", "#mycanvastmp", function() {
    //...
});
```